# Получить строковый ответ от php, предварительно выполнив ajax-запрос

Tags: php

Попытаюсь объяснить путь...
Есть html-страница, в которой при загрузке выполняется ajax-запрос (меняет контент страницы на свой ответ в виде строки => html из строки).

Вот ее результат надо получить из php (echo). 
Обращаясь к url этого php, который выполняет html (в ней ajax), возвращает строку через echo (результат того ajax).

Далеко у муторно, но такая схема нужна :-)

Comment: Ну вот и реализуйте ровно так, как вы описали, в чём проблема-то?

Comment: @andreymal, вопрошающий видимо сам не знает, что ему нужно, так как из текущей версии вопроса я ни чего не понял.

Comment: html-запрос в сторону php -> php, вызывающий html c ajax выполнением -> возврат содержимого html-запросу

Comment: @Visman обновление данных на странице через ajax-запрос к серверу

Comment: Не подходит. HTTP-запрос не может обрабатывать ajax (в моем случае). Этот http-запрос пойдет на сервер, который в свою очередь должен получить данные по ajax, и вернуть его результат

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, делается так.

Пишите хтмл-страницу с дивом куда надо выводить загружаемый контент, подключаете jquery, и аяксом подгружаете контент. В примере ниже:

- `url: 'http://httpbin.org/html'` - путь к вашему php-скрипту, я для примера использовал скрипт вывода тестового хтмл;
- `<div id="content">` - в этот див подгружаем ответ php-скрипта;
- `$.ajax()` - функция подгрузки контента;
- `$('#content').html(e);` - в `<div id="content">` вставляем полученный аяксом котент;
- для того чтобы было видно результат работы я использовал функцию `setTimeout()` которая выполняет ajax-запрос через 2 секунды, но вам она не нужна.

**Html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>titile</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {

      setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://httpbin.org/html',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html'
          })
          .done(function(e) {
            console.log("success");
            $('#content').html(e);
          })
          .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
          })
          .always(function() {
            console.log("complete");
          });
      }, 2000);

    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="content">Сюда загрузится контент, сформированный php-скриптом через 2 секунды... ждите, плеаз.</div>
</body>

</html>
```

`url: 'http://httpbin.org/html'` замените на `url: '/path/phpscript.php'`, где `/path/phpscript.php` - путь к вашему скрипту.

**Содержимое php-скрипта phpscript.php:**

```
echo "Hello world!";
```

На страницу подгрузится и выведется в диве строка `Hello world!`

Comment: Да, это тот html, который выполняется. Но как должен выглядеть php, который запустит исполнение этого htm и заберет содержимое div'а с id=content и сообщит его через echo?

Comment: @dnikitin дополнил ответ